# Per-request lifetime for Unity with OWIN WebApi self-host

Tags: c#, owin, unity-container, self-host-webapi

I am building a WebApi service using OWIN self-hosting (runnable in either console mode or as a Windows service - final deployment to be a service, console mode is for debugging/development). I am having problems with per-request lifetime for Unity injection.

I have previously built other services deployed as IIS WebApi; I added the Unity Mvc nuget along with the basic Unity nuget, follow the directions, and it all works.

In the OWIN self-host environment, I have no problem with default type registrations and `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` registrations, but I can't get `PerRequestLifetimeManager` to work. For one thing, `UnityMvcActivator` doesn't start automatically under OWIN self-host as it does for IIS. If I explicitly call `UnityMvcActivator.Start` when I do, a resolution attempt for type registered with `PerRequestLifetimeManager` results in an  **InvalidOperationException** with the following message:

> The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request.Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

Can `PerRequestLifetimeManager` work with OWIN self-host, or is it dependent on IIS? If it will work under OWIN self-host, how do I get `UnityMvcActivator` to start properly and my injected types registered? If `PerRequestLifetimeManager` is not compatible with OWIN self-host, how else can I register types with per-request lifetimes?

Portion of UnityConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below.
        // Make sure to add a Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your type's mappings here.
        // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

        // My test registration:
        container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    }
```

UnityMvcActivator (as provided in the NuGet, except for the one un-commented line):

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Accounting.Service.UnityMvcActivator), nameof(Accounting.Service.UnityMvcActivator.Start))]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Accounting.Service.UnityMvcActivator), nameof(Accounting.Service.UnityMvcActivator.Shutdown))]

namespace Accounting.Service
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityMvcActivator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Integrates Unity when the application starts.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.Container;

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            UnityConfig.Container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems that the MVC `PerRequestLifetimeManager` won't work in the context I am trying to use it, but I have devised what I think is a work-around using OWIN middleware as follows:

```
public class PerRequestMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    [ThreadStatic] static Dictionary<Type, object> _instances;

    public PerRequestMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        _instances = null;

        await Next.Invoke(context);

        if (_instances != null)
        {
            foreach (var disposable in _instances.Values.OfType<IDisposable>())
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static T GetInstance<T>(Func<T> constructor)
    {
        if (_instances == null)
        {
            _instances = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        var type = typeof(T);

        if (!_instances.TryGetValue(type, out var instance))
        {
            instance = constructor();
            _instances[type] = instance;
        }

        return (T)instance;
    }
}
```

Instead of registering by type, I register factories like this:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
      new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
      {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          RegisterTypes(container);
          return container;
      });

    /// <summary>
    /// Configured Unity Container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or
    /// API controllers (unless you want to change the defaults), as Unity
    /// allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously
    /// registered.
    /// </remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below.
        // Make sure to add a Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your type's mappings here.
        // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

        container.RegisterFactory<ITestService>(c => PerRequestMiddleware.GetInstance(() => new TestService()));
    }
}
```

My question now is: does my work-around contain any flaws or weaknesses?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but after spending hours looking for a good solution I found this blogpost: https://codingsight.com/using-single-ioc-container-http-request-web-api-vs-owin-middleware/

The idea is the same for WebApi and MVC where a Owin Middleware creates the "Scoped Container" or "Child Container" and dependency resolution in ie. MVC is done using this scoped container from the OwinContext.

Answer (score -2):

The code you provided resolves the issue in the `OwinPerRequestUnityMiddleware` project on Github [here](https://github.com/NathanLBCooper/OwinPerRequestUnityMiddleware/issues/2).

However, one thing I noticed when using this code is that `IDisposable` objects get disposed before custom OData serializer providers finish creating resources.

If you need an object even after the lifetime of the OWIN pipeline, you can use a `Factory` class in the container.

For example, instead of using a `DbContext`, use `IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>`.